# How do you properly switch development device with unstaged changes?

Tags: git, git-stash

I've been developing across 2 devices.

What I would usually do, when needing to head out and use my laptop, is mass stage my pending changes, commit them, and push them so I can resume development by pulling from my laptop later on.

However, obviously it's a bad practice to just stage a bunch of random changes and push them under a blanket commit.

Is there some way to push a *git stash*, pull the stash, and have all the stages pending still, on the other device.

Comment: “However, obviously it's a bad practice to just stage a bunch of random changes and push them under a blanket commit.” Why is it bad practice? As long as you stick it on a temporary branch used only for this purpose, what harm is done? How is a stash any different?

Comment: @matt, but now these changes are committed for good, and I can't go back and properly document / commit them - unless I did some weird hacking to uncommit them etc.

Comment: So forget the second computer. In real life you just edit and edit without ever making a commit on any branch until you’ve got it all sorted into nice neat little piles? It seems to me THAT is the “bad practice”.

Comment: @matt in between commits, I, *rarely*, rely on jetbrains' local history

Comment: @Tobiq I guess what matt hints at is the "commit often" practice, which is a good point. Not invalidating the need to sometimes "transport" unfinished work, but I see his point.

Comment: I also see the point, If I'd been committing 5 times a minute, I'd not have any unstaged changes - I'd just have less work done.

Comment: But you are getting less work done already if you are afraid to commit because you don’t want any commits that don’t tell a lovely story.

Answer (score 5):

Doing a commit on a temporary branch that you then push isn't breaking any Git idioms. You can clean up commit messages and the like later.

If you're set against using an actual commit, you can stash and then save the stash in patch format.

```
git stash #stash everything
git stash show -p > stash.diff #save patch-formatted stash to file
```

Then you just need to get the `stash.diff` file onto the second machine and do `git apply stash.diff`.

Comment: Although this is essentially what I was looking for, the other solution seems more elegant - because it's working only using git commands, and no file sharing

Comment: I find it more convenient to use a commit on the branch itself and not need external ways to send/apply the patch, but to be honest this is simple, working,and maybe closer to the expressed need.

Answer (score 4):

If you're alone on the branch and don't have to share its history with coworkers, what I'd suggest is to use a temporary commit :

From Machine 1, on your branch :

```
# you have unfinished modifications to "save"
git commit -am "temp"
git push origin HEAD
```

From Machine 2, on your branch :

```
# get your last commit like you usually do, let's say
git pull

# now let's "uncommit" the ugly temp
git reset HEAD^
```

(as a reminder, `git reset` without `--soft` or `--hard` makes it a default `--mixed` mode. It makes that modifications are kept in the working tree, so it's only the branch pointer which is set to a different commit)

At this point you have the pending modifications from Machine 1, ready to be furtherly modified, added and "properly" commited when you're ready.

---

Lastly, as you asked in comment, yes, you'll have to force push either way when you want to reflect back on the remote (which still has the temp commit you locally destroyed, to be replaced with yours).

And of course thanks to [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) for the useful optimization.

Comment: Looks like a good solution. You'd have to do a forced push right, because you're then behind the origin?

Comment: @Tobiq Exactly, good point I forgot to mention. I've edited to add it.

Comment: You can simplify the pair of resets to `git reset HEAD^`, which is short for `git reset --mixed HEAD^`: set the branch pointer back one and load the index from the newly selected commit while leaving the work-tree alone.

Comment: @torek You're right, I've edited my answer accordingly (and my work aliases too, mind you). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the premise of your question is incorrect:

> obviously it's a bad practice to just stage a bunch of random changes and push them under a blanket commit

No, it isn't. Stage all the changes into a blanket commit, and retrieve them on the other machine.

Two observations:

- The fear of committing everything in a lump because there hasn't been time to sort it all out into a lovely rationalized history is a Bad Smell in the workflow. Commit early and often! There'll be time to sort it all out later in [post-production](http://sethrobertson.github.io/GitPostProduction/gpp.html).
- If the worry is that rewriting history later is an anti-pattern because this branch is shared with others on the repository, then *don't* share this branch with others on the repository. If necessary, track this branch on *another* remote. That's what I do; I expose my work publicly on github but only after I've configured everything privately on bitbucket, which has branches that never get pushed to github.

Comment: Of course, all of this omits the possibility of just copying the project folder from the desktop to the portable before rushing out the door.